# Expand all/Collapse all button js

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm using this W3Schools tutorial to create some collapsibles. I'd like to create two buttons which could collapse or expand all the collapsibles. 
I've included the codesnippet i am using. I can't seem to create two working buttons so i've just posted the code i am currently working with.

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) 
{
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() 
  {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight)
    {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } 
    else 
    {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
<style>
.collapsible {
    background-color: #777;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.content {
    padding: 0 18px;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not jquery - as the title suggests.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are trying to achieve, right? This is just an illustration using jQuery. You can modify it in the way you want it.

```js
$('.item').on('click', '.header', function(){
  $('.item').removeClass('show')
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('show')
})
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 5px;
}
.header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.content {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.item.show .content {
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class='item'>
  <div class='header'>Item 1</div>
  <div class='content'>Content 1</div>
</section>

<section class='item'>
  <div class='header'>Item 1</div>
  <div class='content'>Content 2</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code extended.

I think this is what you asked for

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) 
{
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() 
  {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight)
    {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } 
    else 
    {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}

var expA = document.getElementById('expAll');
    expA.addEventListener('click', function() {
      expandFunction(true);
    }, false);

    var collA = document.getElementById('collAll');
    collA.addEventListener('click', function() {
      expandFunction(false);
    }, false);

    function expandFunction(x) {
      var details = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
      Array.from(details).forEach(span => {
        var content = span.nextElementSibling;
        var condition;
        var result;
        switch (x) {
          case false:
            condition = content.style.maxHeight == content.scrollHeight + "px";
            result = null;
            break;
          case true:
            condition = content.style.maxHeight == null || content.style.maxHeight == "";
            result = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            break;
          default:
        }
        if (condition) {
          span.classList.toggle("active");
          content.style.maxHeight = result;
        }
      });
    }
```

```css
<style>
.collapsible {
    background-color: #777;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.content {
    padding: 0 18px;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>

<a href='#8' id='expAll'>Expand All</a>
<a href='#9' id='collAll'>Collapse All<br></a>

</head>

<body>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```